# NotificationCompat.Builder constructor not available

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have the use case where I need to modify a `Notification` after it is received in an `Intent` via a `BroadcastReceiver`. Looking through docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#%3Cinit%3E(android.content.Context,%20android.app.Notification)) for `NotificationCompat.Builder` there's this constructor listed:

```
Builder(@NonNull context: Context, @NonNull notification: Notification)
```

With the description:

> Creates a NotificationCompat.Builder which can be used to build a
> notification that is equivalent to the given one, such that updates
> can be made to an existing notification with the
> NotitifactionCompat.Builder API.

BUT, this constructor is not recognized when I try to use it, nor is it listed in the actual source. I upgraded my targeted and compiled sdk versions to 30 with no luck (my minimum is 21). Does this mean it's more than likely a future change?

Is there another way I can clone a `Notification` into a `Builder` object to modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause**

[NotificationCompat.Builder(Context, Notification)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#init) constructor is available from Android AppCompat Library 1.3.0-alpha02, it seems you are using the older version that why you cannot use it from the code.

**Solution**

Step 1. Update the Android AppCompat Library to 1.3.0-alpha02 version.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02'
```

Step 2. Use from a Kotlin class

```
val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, existingNotification)
```